# Suspicious behaviour of Facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-apps

In the recent days I have noticed suspicious activity in my account probably due to some apps I had added in my account. There were autolikes and automatic follows appearing in my account. So I checked my account , undid all the automated actions and checked my privacy settings to see which apps had access and I removed almost all except the ones which are highly trusted and I use regularly.

However yesterday morning an extremely vulgar spam link was posted from my account which was seen by people at my work. I informed everyone that I hadn't posted it , deleted it and as an immediate measure I have deactivated my account.

I am afraid such things may happen again when I reactivate my account as I have already checked which apps have access to my account . I need assistance in ensuring that such activities are not repeated in my account. Kindly guide me on what steps I can take to ensure safety of my account.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of situation comes when you clicked on a rogue app link. A lot of times things that are designed to make you want to click them end up installing an app on your Facebook account that will send out stuff.

Here what Facebook said about [how to deal with spam](https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/217854714899185):

> Spam is sometimes spread through clicking on bad links or installing malicious software. On other occasions, scammers gain access to people's Facebook accounts, which are then used to send out spam.
>
> If you clicked on something that turned out to be spam or your account is creating unwanted posts, events, groups or Pages, try these steps:
>
> **Secure your account**
>
> - If you can log into your account, we recommend [changing your password](https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/213395615347144?helpref=faq_content). If you can't get into your account, you can [secure it](https://en-gb.facebook.com/hacked).
> - If someone is repeatedly posting something you think is spam, consider [unfriending](https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/172936839431357?helpref=faq_content), [blocking](https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/168009843260943?helpref=faq_content) or [reporting](https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/171757096241231?helpref=faq_content) that person.

First thing change your account password. Follow the all instructions given in first link. It will help you to secure your account.